# Scrolling down two windows of the same program at the same time in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, pdf

Is it possible to choose two windows of same program or different programs and scroll the windows down simultaneously? I have two pdf documents that I want to scroll down simultaneously.

Comment: Only if the app is written to allow this. For instance most Diff programs do.

Comment: Most windows apps don't seem like.

Comment: See this previous thread - https://superuser.com/questions/497105/autohotkey-scrolling-two-pdf-documents

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Word 2010 and later version has a Synchronous Scrolling function.

[image]

But for PDF viewers such as Microsoft Edge or Adobe PDF reader, it’s impossible.

Some user mentioned that scroll together function can be achieved by script, but I don’t familiar with scripting, maybe you can check this link for some ideas.

Scrolling in two documents at the same time?

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1490163